# Adding featured image via PHP

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, uploads

Currently I'm working on a project where site is driven by user articles, how it works:

1. Any user goes to compose post page
   and writes post along with few
   details, has upload file option for
   image and then submits
2. Post is uploaded in wordpress and the image attached is set as featured image
3. Admin approves the post and it gets published.

Here user is not required to have an account. I am using `wp_insert_post` to create a new post but not able to figure out how to add featured image via PHP.

Comment: does it have to be added via .php or could you consider a plugin?

Comment: http://vudu.me/6n is a writeup I did a bit ago, I think it may be what you are looking for?

Comment: I would prefer php code because the plugin itself would be in php. Custom written code is more secure and efficient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [set_post_thumbnail](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post.php#L5128) function.

```
set_post_thumbnail( $post_ID, $thumbnail_id );
```

Require you use WordPress 3.1.0 or later.

You need call this function after you have successfully created your post via `wp_insert_post` and have a valid `$post_ID`.

Comment: Hmm... that's one of them things I missed in 3.1. Thanks for pointing that out!